# Generating a hexagon grid 20x15, but getting a single column instead

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a hexagon grid, but instead they appear in a vertical line. How should I fix this?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const gridContainer = document.getElementById("hexagon-grid");
  const numberOfColumns = 15;
  const numberOfRows = 20;

  generateHexagonGrid(gridContainer, numberOfColumns, numberOfRows);

  zigzagEvenColumns(gridContainer, numberOfColumns);
});

function generateHexagonGrid(container, columns, rows) {
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
      const hexagon = document.createElement("div");
      hexagon.classList.add("hex-grid__content");
      container.appendChild(hexagon);
    }
  }
}

function zigzagEvenColumns(container, columns) {
  const hexagons = container.getElementsByClassName("hex-grid__content");

  for (let col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
    if (col % 2 === 0) {

      const columnIndex = col * rows;

      for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        const hexagonIndex = columnIndex + row;
        const hexagon = hexagons[hexagonIndex];

        if (hexagon) {
          hexagon.style.transform = "translateY(-20px)";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hex-grid__content {
  /* position:relative; */
  height: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #b86d6d;
  background-color: rgb(185, 224, 211);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.24s ease-out;
  margin-bottom: 0.1px;
}

.hex-grid__content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon-grid"></div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of how to use the browser debug tools? Typically opened by pressing F12 - I ask as there's an error that you've not mentioned in your question that you might be unaware of: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: rows is not defined"_

Comment: why don't you use SVG instead?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by a hexagon grid? Are the  elements in the grid to be as tightly together as possible - like a honeycomb?

Comment: Continuing along the lines of what @AHaworth asked, is this your desired setup? https://jsfiddle.net/x7rgdatz/